# Inserting into multiple tables and selecting the first result

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Let's say I have two tables that implement a very simple invoice system (note: the schema can't be changed):

```
create table invoices(
  id serial primary key,
  parent_invoice_id int null references invoices(id),
  name text not null
);
create table line_items(
  id serial primary key,
  invoice_id int not null references invoices(id),
  amount int not null
);
```

The user has the ability to "clone" an invoice and have it refer to the original "parent" invoice. In the system, the *invoice* is required directly after the clone (however the `line_items` are not required). Therefore, after cloning the invoice, the new invoice must be returned. Here's the SQL I'm using to clone an invoice:

```
with new_invoice_row as (
  insert into invoices (parent_invoice_id, name)
  values (12345/*invoice_to_clone_id*/, 'Hello World')
  returning *
),
new_line_item_rows as (
  insert into line_items (invoice_id, amount)
  select
    new_invoice_row.id, line_item.amount
  from line_items
  cross join new_invoice_row
  where
    line_item.invoice_id = 12345/*invoice_to_clone_id*/
  returning id
)
select * from new_invoice_row;
```

Questions:

1. Is the `cross join` going to perform well? I was thinking of being able to just remove the `cross join` to reduce having to do the join, but it wouldn't run (error: `missing FROM-clause entry for table "new_invoice_row"`):

   ```
   ...
   insert into line_items (invoice_id, amount)
   select
     new_invoice_row.id, line_item.amount
   from line_items
   where
     line_item.invoice_id = 12345
   returning id
   ...
   ```
2. Is there anyway that the `returning id` part of the `new_line_item_rows` statement can be removed? The new line items aren't needed, so I'd like to avoid the extra overhead if it can improve performance.
3. Should I stop using a query and move all of this into a function? The system was originally using a MS SQL database, so I'm more familiar with using `declare` and having multiple statements use the variable.

Comment: There are two FKs missing from your DDL: `parent_invoice_id integer REFERENCES invoices(id)` and `invoice_id integer not null REFERENCES invoices(id)`

Comment: @wildplasser Yup, sorry. I just wrote this up without actually using the *real* tables :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query can return only `id` and `parent_invoice_id`.
Use the second value in order to avoid re-writing the argument (as a protection against typos).
Cross join is necessary and correct. 
You can skip `returning *` in the second query.
A function is not necessary, although it may be convenient to use.

```
with new_invoice_row as (
  insert into invoices (parent_invoice_id, name)
  values (12345, 'Hello World')
  returning id, parent_invoice_id
),
new_line_item_rows as (
  insert into line_items (invoice_id, amount)
  select
    new_invoice_row.id, line_items.amount
  from line_items
  cross join new_invoice_row
  where
    line_items.invoice_id = new_invoice_row.parent_invoice_id
)
select * from new_invoice_row;
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there now way to return the full row for the `new_invoice_row`? Is there a way to perform the select of the row *afterwards*?

Comment: You can do it in another query. I would opt however for using `returning *` in the first query. The cost of cross join should not be crucial.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table invoices(
  id serial primary key,
  parent_invoice_id int null references invoices(id),
  name text not null
);
INSERT INTO invoices(parent_invoice_id, name) VALUES
 ( NULL, 'One')
,( 1, 'two')
,( NULL, 'three')
 ;
create table line_items(
  id serial primary key,
  invoice_id int not null references invoices(id),
  amount int not null
);
INSERT INTO line_items (invoice_id, amount) VALUES
 (1, 10)
,(1, 11)
,(2, 21)
,(2, 22)
,(3, 33)
   ;


-- for demonstration purposes: the clone+insert as a prepared statement
-- (this is *not* necessary, only convenient)
PREPARE clone_the_invoice (INTEGER, text, INTEGER) AS
    WITH new_invoice_row as (
    INSERT into invoices (parent_invoice_id, name)
    VALUES ( $1 /*invoice_to_clone_id*/, $2 /*name */ )
    RETURNING id)
, new_line_item_rows as (
    INSERT into line_items (invoice_id, amount)
    SELECT new_invoice_row.id, $3 /* amount */
    FROM new_invoice_row
    RETURNING id
    )
SELECT * FROM new_line_item_rows
        ;

 -- call the prepared statement.
 -- This will clone invoice#2, 
 -- and insert one row in items, referring to the cloned row
 -- it returns the new item's id, which is sufficient to
 -- find the invoice.id too, when needed.
 -- -----------------------------------------------------------------
EXECUTE clone_the_invoice (2, 'four', 123);


 -- Chek the result
SELECT
  iv.id
  , iv.parent_invoice_id
  , iv.name
  , li.id AS lineid
  , li.amount
FROM invoices iv
JOIN line_items li ON li.invoice_id = iv.id
        ;
```

---

Result:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 3
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 5
PREPARE
 id 
----
  6
(1 row)

 id | parent_invoice_id | name  | lineid | amount 
----+-------------------+-------+--------+--------
  1 |                   | One   |      1 |     10
  1 |                   | One   |      2 |     11
  2 |                 1 | two   |      3 |     21
  2 |                 1 | two   |      4 |     22
  3 |                   | three |      5 |     33
  4 |                 2 | four  |      6 |    123
(6 rows)
```

---

And for non-trivial cases, the FKs will need a supporting index (this is not added automatically, so you should do this manually)

```
CREATE INDEX ON invoices (parent_invoice_id);
CREATE INDEX ON line_items (invoice_id);
```

---

Update: if you insist on returning the new invoice, here you go:

```
PREPARE clone_the_invoice2 (INTEGER, text, integer) AS
    WITH new_invoice_row as (
    INSERT into invoices (parent_invoice_id, name)
    VALUES ( $1 /*invoice_to_clone_id*/, $2 )
    RETURNING *
    )
, new_line_item_rows as (
    INSERT into line_items (invoice_id, amount)
    SELECT new_invoice_row.id, $3
    FROM new_invoice_row
    RETURNING *
    )
SELECT iv.*
FROM new_invoice_row iv
JOIN new_line_item_rows new ON new.invoice_id = iv.id
    ;
```

---

UPDATE 2 (it appears the OP wants the *detail lines* to be cloned, too:

```
    -- Clone an invoice
    -- INCLUDING all associated line_items
    -- --------------------------------------
PREPARE clone_the_invoice3 (INTEGER, text) AS
    WITH new_invoice_row as (
    INSERT into invoices (parent_invoice_id, name)
    VALUES      ( $1 /*invoice_to_clone_id*/
                , $2 /* name */
                )
    RETURNING *
    )
, new_line_item_rows as (
    INSERT into line_items (invoice_id, amount)
    SELECT cl.id                -- the cloned invoice
        , it.amount
    FROM line_items it
    CROSS JOIN new_invoice_row cl
    WHERE it.invoice_id = $1    -- The original invoice
    RETURNING *
    )
SELECT iv.*
FROM new_invoice_row iv
JOIN new_line_item_rows new ON new.invoice_id = iv.id
        ;


EXECUTE clone_the_invoice3 (2, 'four');
```

Comment: Thanks. However, this doesn't return the row for the new invoice (not the line items) as stated in the question.

Comment: You can always retrieve that by using line_items.invoice_id as in my example. (you could add it as an extra element to CTE, chain. my final join is a good starting point)

Comment: The only thing is that the line items aren't required, only the invoice. So, there is the cost of the join of the line items (when they're not used).

Comment: There is no *cost of a join*, the join is just piggybacked on the existing query. Everything that is needed is already there.

Comment: I also just noticed that this doesn't do the same thing as my original query. This doesn't copy the `amount` of each line item, it passes it as a parameter.

Comment: So you want to clone an invloice, **including all associated line_items** Why didn't you say so in your question?

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that it was required if you look at the query that was posted in the OP.